# How to make double chevron >> in Firefox.

Tags: firefox-addon

I am making my own toolbar in Firefox. Can anyone tell me how to add a double chevron `>>` so that if window resizes the toolbar content can be seen by clicking this double chevron `>>`?

Answer (score 2):

This should be automatic. If you have more buttons on your toolbar than you have width to display them all firefox should automatically give you the 'more' drop down.

Comment: i am making my own toolbar as firfox addon.it is not showing automatically.i am confussed. what changes i need to do in .css file